# Implementation details about costmap_2d package

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am a newbie in programming and ROS, so please pardon me if my queries sound naive.

I am working on using semantic information for robot navigation. I have a conceptual architecture ready and would like to implement it using ROS. For this as a beginning step what I would like to do is as follows:

Inflate each obstacle with different inflation radii, and not one common inflation radius set by user.

I am planning to implement an object of costmap_2d and write a method to fill in costs based on the inflation radius specified for that object.

However, since I am a beginner, I am not able to understand the implementation part. Like once the instance of costmap_2d is created in move_base (i guess) what are the implementation steps involved to fill it with cost values and finally publish it to the planner. Is there any documentation existing for the same? Or if some one could guide me with the same?

Thank you in advance and any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199071/implementation-details-about-costmap_2d-package/) by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a perfect use case for layered costmaps. For details check out my [paper on the subject](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/?p=200) as well as my [ROSCON talk](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/?p=215).

For implementation details, check out [the tutorials here.](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials)

**Edit**: 1) The layers can build off of each other when updating values.  2) Correct.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2